# Can i hotwire my home with a modified extension cord?

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel

Is it possible to hotwire your home with a double male extention cord by connecting one end to a hot plug and the other to an outlet in your home that has no power? Or more specifically connect your neighbour live car plug into my dead car plug then another in the apt kitchen plug into the other kitchen plug and finally a third double male from the last kitchen plug into bedrom or livingroom. Is this possible.

Comment: extremely dangerous

Comment: Why on Earth are you trying to shock the living daylights out of yourself and/or a poor, unsuspecting utility linesman heroically trying to fix your power?

Comment: Can you [edit](https://diy.stackexchange.com/posts/145942/edit) your question with more information about your situation even?

Comment: Settle down stop and think what will happen . its not as much of a question as i need an answer but a test to see what is really known about electricity . ill tell you now i already know the answer.  You will be surprised at what you can do and what they dont teach you.

Comment: Look.....all you would be advisors ill tell you now that anyone can energize their home enough to run a fridge few lights and a clock radio simply by using a double sided male cord. Pluging one end into a live outlet and the other into an outlet in your home. This is a fact i am doing it right now

Comment: There is a way  to reduce you power bill by 90%? Just ask

Comment: @Preston well yeah, burning your house down would probably cut your power bill down by about 100%.

Comment: Well, ThreePhaseEel has 26k rep, I have north of 50k rep, I have read probably 50% of residential NEC, *and* I have done *great loads* of backfeeding as I restored electrical in a factory we bought, even backfed a transformer with a 300' #16 extension cord so I could light up other panelboards. I know how to do this stuff. **You do not**. Yes it "seems to work" but it's dangerous and recklessly stupid **for reasons you can't even understand** because you are too goal-focused.  I can do that thing too; but I can do it **safe and legal**.  It's so stupid-easy to do it right; why don't you care?

Comment: Sure it can be done, at the cost of a possible negligent homicide case or starting a fire.

Answer (score 6):

## STOP. NO. DO NOT GO DOWN THIS ROAD.  THERE ARE DEAD BODIES ON IT.

First off -- male bits go on things that receive power and female bits go on things that provide power for a very good reason: it was designed this way on purpose so that you don't have exposed powered bits roaming around waiting to zap you.

Second, trying to send power to the utility when the utility is dead is a good way to fry a linesman and/or your generator (or your neighbor's electrical system).

Third, *why* does your house not have electricity?  Tell us more details about what's going on here by editing your question, and we can give you better answers.

Answer (score 1):

### No! No! No! No! No!

Is it *possible*?  Sure.  But it would require a depth of stupidity and a *profound* indifference for human life.  Why do that when it's so easy for a remotely smart person to do it safe and legal?

I do these things all the time. I use a very simple principle:

### Permanent wiring needn't be

If I have an event like "Oh hey, power's out, I want to power up Circuit 19", that's a 5 minute job for me.  Main off, service panel cover off, I grab a power cord (male to stripped wires), snake the power cord through a service panel knockout and put a strain relief on it,  attach cord ground to panel ground, pull hot off breaker 19 and nut it to hot on the power cord, pull circuit 19's neutral off the neutral bar and nut it to neutral on the power cord. Tighten down the strain relief, test, panel cover on, donezo.

No big deal, and that's a perfectly Code legal way to do that.  It follows permanent installation rules (400.7 as far as the flexible cord) and could be continued in service *indefinitely* safe and legal.

Of course, I'll reverse it the next day, but it still counts.

Oh, want to power up circuits 19 and 21?  (noting they are on opposite *poles*.)  Then both 19 and 21's neutral get nutted to the power cord's neutral, both their hots get nutted to the power cord's hot. Extend as needed.

So why would I do something **completely moronic** that endangers both my family and linemen?

Why would I do a lousy job that adds a ton of risk *for no useful purpose whatsoever*?

### Now, if I expect this to happen regularly...

Then there are a few other ways to go with that.  One is to terminate the to-be-switched circuits *not* in the service panel, but instead in a nice large 4-11/16" or 6" square steel box with a short (<24") run of steel conduit to the panel.  Heck, leave the power cord dangling out of this box.  Now you're doing the same things as above, just doing it inside this box instead of the panel.  (terminate each circuit's ground at the steel box and let the conduit carry it to the panel).

Another option is terminate the circuit in that same box, but give each circuit a very short power cord - it can either reach a receptacle powered from the breaker; or it can go the other way and reach a power strip I bolted to the wall.  The power strip plugs into my genny or alternate source.

An other option is to use some DPDT switches (a bit spendy - *no, you can't use 3-ways*) and switch both hot and neutral between either panel or single cord.   But at that fairly expensive price point, I'd just look at fitting a proper subpanel with gen interlock. Siemens has a gen interlock kit for their main-lug panels for $20.  I certainly wouldn't pay $300 for one.

But, you know, electrical is something I do with great pride.  YMMV.